# Trying to append JSON items to array but not working

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I am trying to serialize a GET request then make a movie object, then appending that movie object to a movies array which I will use to show info on the UI.

I am new and have struggled with this problem for some time now :(

If you look at the `self.movies?.append(movie)` shouldnt that work? I dont see any reasons as to when i try to get the first item i get fatal error index out of bounds which means I the Array is not filled yet.... Dont know what i am doing wrong :(

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var movies:[Movie]? = []

@IBOutlet weak var uiMovieTitle: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    getMovieData()
    print(self.movies?.count)
    setUI()


}

@IBAction func yesBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(movies?[5].title ?? String())
}

@IBAction func seenBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

}

@IBAction func noBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

}


@IBOutlet weak var moviePoster: UIImageView!


let urlString = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=935f539acbfed4b9e5534ddeed3fb57e&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=12"

func getMovieData(){
    //Set up URL
    let todoEndPoint: String = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=935f539acbfed4b9e5534ddeed3fb57e&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=12"

    guard let url = URL(string: todoEndPoint) else {

        print("Cant get URL")
        return
    }

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    //Setting up session
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession.shared

    //Task setup
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, URLResponse, error) in

        //Checking for errors
        guard error == nil else{
            print("Error calling GET")
            print(error)
            return
        }
        //Checking if we got data
        guard let responseData = data else{
            print("Error: No data")
            return
        }

        self.movies = [Movie]()

        do{//If we got data, if not print error

            guard let todo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options:.mutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject] else{

                print("Error trying to convert data to JSON")
                return


            }//if data is Serializable, do this


            if let movieResults = todo["results"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
                //For each movieobject inside of movieresult try to make a movie object
                for moviesFromJson in movieResults{

                    let movie = Movie()

                    //If all this works, set variables
                    if let title = moviesFromJson["title"] as? String, let movieRelease = moviesFromJson["release_date"] as? String, let posterPath = moviesFromJson["poster_path"] as? String, let movieId = moviesFromJson["id"] as? Int{

                        movie.title = title
                        movie.movieRelease = movieRelease
                        movie.posterPath = posterPath
                        movie.movieId = movieId


                    }

                    self.movies?.append(movie)

                }

            }
        }//do end

        catch{
            print(error)
        }


    }
    ////Do Stuff



    task.resume()

}

func setUI(){

    //uiMovieTitle.text = self.movies![0].title
    //print(self.movies?[0].title)
}
```

}

my Movie class:

```
import UIKit

class Movie: NSObject {


var title:String?
var movieRelease: String?
var posterPath:String?
var movieId:Int?
var movieGenre:[Int] = []

//public init(title:String, movieRelease:String, posterPath:String,movieId:Int) {
  //  self.movieId = movieId
    //self.title = title
    //self.movieRelease = movieRelease
    //self.posterPath = posterPath
    //self.movieGenre = [movieGenre]



//}
```

}

Comment: Don't try to append inside the GET call, it will do it async so you will get that error, try to do it in the callback, if you don't know how to do it please ask and I will try to explain it with example code

Comment: Thank you for such a quick answer! Yes i dont know how to do it and can you please explain :) Because I do see what you mean but I dont know how or where I should do it :)

Comment: okey let me, I will make a new answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getMovieData` calls the network asynchronously. Your `viewDidLoad` invokes this, then calls `setUI()` - but the networking is still ongoing when setUI is called.

Instead, call `setUI` when the networking is complete - after the `self.movies?.append(movie)` line. The UI code will need to happen on the main thread. So...

```
for moviesFromJson... // your existing code
    ...
    self.movies?.append(movie)
}

// Refresh UI now movies have loaded.
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    setUI()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var movies:[Movie]? = []

    @IBOutlet weak var uiMovieTitle: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        getMovieDataCall(completionHandler: {data, error in self. getMovieDataCallBack(data: data, error: error)})

    }

func getMovieDataCallBack(data: Data?, error: Error?) {
        if error == nil {
            let dictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            //do your appending here and then call setUI()
            print("dictionaryMovie \(dictionary)")
        } else {
            showAlertView("", error?.localizedDescription)
        }
}

    func getMovieDataCall(completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void)){
        //Set up URL
        let todoEndPoint: String = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=935f539acbfed4b9e5534ddeed3fb57e&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=12"

        guard let url = URL(string: todoEndPoint) else {

            print("Cant get URL")
            return
        }

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

        //Setting up session
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession.shared

        //Task setup
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, URLResponse, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    NSLog("GET-ERROR", "=\(error)");
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                } else {
                    let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
                    print(dataString!)
                    completionHandler(data, nil)
                }

        task.resume()

    }

    func setUI(){

    }
```

Comment: you see you have to make the Get request first, have a completion handler for that, when it is done and you have no error do the appending, then refresh your UI, hope this helps, if it needs explaining please ask